# How do I add a new column to Rails Mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I currently have the columns id, name, email, linkedin, company, contacted, recruiter, student and I want to add a new one called responded.  I'm only finding answers on how to add new columns to all the existing instances in my db.  So I did try this:

`db.people.update({}, {$set: {"responded": false}}, false, true)`

All my existing instances have a field :responded set to false by default.  When I try to add a new person now I'm getting this error:

```
Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute in PeopleController#create



 message: Attempted to set a value for 'responded' which is not allowed on the model Person. summary: Without including Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic in your model and the attribute does not already exist in the attributes hash, attempting to call Person#responded= for it is not allowed. This is also triggered by passing the attribute to any method that accepts an attributes hash, and is raised instead of getting a NoMethodError. resolution: You can include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic if you expect to be writing values for undefined fields often.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have "columns", it does not have tables either. You have documents with fields.

I imagine you are using MongoID for your models, so you only need to define the field on your model

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :middle_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :responded, type: Boolean # something like this
end
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#fields